# Using a specific branch of a meteorite package

Tags: meteor, package, meteorite

How do i specify or change the version of a package i want to use with atmosphere? Can i pass in the git branch to my smart.json file as an option ? Something like this in the smart.json file ? I would like to run off of a git version and have meteor grab and use that version when running the application.

Here is what i have tried doing which errors with version does not exist

```
"packages": {

     iron-router: {
        version: {"https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/dev"} 
     }

   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited per comment below (don't leave this on dev!!! but things are changing quickly):

```
iron-router: {
    "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router" ,
    "branch": "dev"
  }
}
```

Have you tried this syntax?

```
iron-router: {
    "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/dev" ,
    "branch": "master"
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I just had to change `"branch": "dev"` and remove the `"/tree/dev"` from the git property

Answer (score 0):

wanted to install `iron-router-progess` too, didn't allow me to do that with the master branch so I had to remove iron-router, change `smart.json` to

```
{
  "packages": {
    "bootstrap-3": {},
    "iron-router": {
      "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router",
      "branch": "dev"
    },
    "dimsum": {},
    "iron-router-progress": {}
  }
}
```

and run `mrt update` again. Works fine now.